# How can i emmit key values in the end of the whole file processing?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Mapper reads lines from file... How can i emmit key values in the end, after the whole scanning of the file and not per line?

Answer (score 2):

Using the new mapreduce API, you can override the `Mapper.cleanup(Context)` method and use `Context.write(K, V)` as you normally would in the map method.

```
@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) {
  context.write(new Text("key"), new Text("value"));
}
```

The old mapred API you can override the `close()` method - but you'll need to store a reference to the `OutputCollector` given to the map method:

```
private OutputCollector cachedCollector = null;

void map(Longwritable key, Text value, OutputCollector outputCollector, Reporter reporter) {
  if (cachedCollector == null) {
    cachedCollector = outputCollector;
  }

  // ...
}

public void close() {
  cachedCollector.collect(outputKey, outputValue);
}
```

Comment: I use the new API... What do you mean to overide the cleanup(Context)... I dont hav lot of experience in Hadoop

Comment: Updated to include an example cleanup method - put it in your mapper class (the class that currently contains your map method)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one Key value for whole file or multiple?

If it is case #1:
Use WholeFileInputFormat. You will receive full file content as a single record. You can split this into records, process all the records and emit final Key/Value at the end of your processing

Cae #2:
Use same fileInputFormat. Store all key values in a temp storage. At the end, access your temp storage and emit whatever the Key/values you want and suppress those you don't want

Comment: Yes i have one Key value for the Whole file...But if i use WholeFileInputFormat will the system in parallel or i will process data in a single machine????

Comment: I have many files all in the same folder with the same key... This mapper is in the Job2 and the files were created in the Job1

Comment: There will be one map created per file in this case. Hence whole file is processed on one machine. Separate files are processed by separate map tasks which means each file may be processed on different machines. If you want to have a single Key and Map across all the files they you need to add reduce step to appropriately aggregate the output from the map tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Chris's answer could be that you can achieve this by overriding the `run()` of the Mapper class (New API)

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

  //map method here

  // Override the run()
  @override
  public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
  // Have your last <key,value> emitted here
  context.write(lastOutputKey, lastOutputValue);
  cleanup(context);
  }
}
```

And in order to ensure that each mapper gets one file to process, you have to create your own version of `FileInputFormat` and *override* `isSplittable()`, like this:

```
Class NonSplittableFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat{

@Override 
    public boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename){ 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work in one machine up the end of the file or in parallel?

Comment: @EleftheriosK. Checkout the edited answer, now you should be able to run it with any number of machines with any number of files in parallel.